# Cypress sharing variables/alias between Hooks?

Tags: cypress

```
So I have a pretty `before` and `beforeEach` function that runs before all tests. It looks something like this:

describe("JWT Authentication", function() {
  before(function() {
    // custom command runs once to get token for JWT auth
    // alias token as 'user' for further use
    cy.get_auth_token().as('user')
  })
  beforeEach(function() {
    // before each page load, set the JWT to the aliased 'user' token
    cy.visit("/", {
      onBeforeLoad(win) {
        // set the user object in local storage
        win.localStorage.setItem("token", this.user.token);
      }
    })
  })
  it("a single test...", function() {
   //do stuff
});
```

The custom command is also pretty simple:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("get_auth_token", () => {
    cy.request("POST", Cypress.env("auth_url"), {
        username: Cypress.env("auth_username"),
        password: Cypress.env("auth_password")
      })
        .its("body")
        .then(res => {
          return res;
        });
})
```

The custom command itself works and retrieves the token as expected. However when it comes to the `beforeEach` it has no idea what `this.user.token` is. Specifically not knowing what `user` is.

One option is of course calling the command in every `beforeEach` which is what the JWT Cypress recipe/example spec does. However this feels excessive because in my case I do not NEED to grab the token every test. I only need to grab it once for this set of tests.

So how can I share the token to the beforeEach hook with a Cypress custom command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a few tests, all the bits seem to work!

The following does not give you an answer, but may help you debug.

**Passing token between before() and beforeEach()**

Assume we have a user in `before()`, does it get to the `onBeforeLoad()` callback?

```js
describe("JWT Authentication", function() {

  before(function() {
    const mockUser = { token: 'xyz' }; 
    cy.wrap(mockUser).as('user');
  })

  beforeEach(function() {
    cy.visit("http://example.com", {
      onBeforeLoad(win) {
        console.log(this.user.title);  // prints 'xyz'
      }
    })
  })
  it("a single test...", function() {
   //do stuff
  })
});
```

**Is the custom command working**

I can't find a generic mock for an Auth check, but any `cy.request()` that gets an object should be equivalent.

I'm hitting typicode.com and looking for the title property

```js
describe("JWT Authentication", function() {

  Cypress.Commands.add("get_auth_token", () => {
    cy.request("GET", 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .its("body")
      .then(body => {
         console.log('body', body); // prints {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false}
         return body;
       });
  })

  before(function() {
    cy.get_auth_token()
      .then(user => console.log('user', user)) // prints {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false}
      .as('user')
  })

  beforeEach(function() {
    cy.visit("http://example.com", {
      onBeforeLoad(win) {
        console.log(this.user.title);  // prints 'delectus aut autem'
      }
    })
  })
  it("a single test...", function() {
   //do stuff
  })
});
```

**Custom command**

This shorter version also seems to work

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("get_auth_token", () => {
  cy.request("GET", 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .its("body");
})
```

Comment: I can't make this work between beforeEach and afterEach.

Comment: It works great for me. `afterEach()` was not mentioned in the question, but is very useful to show how to debug.